# Run a script after killing lxsession (xorg)

Tags: linux, bash, xorg, tty, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run a program automatically within a bash script after killing the LXDE session. My script consists of:

```
#!/bin/sh
pkill lxsession;
sh /home/pi/RetroPie/EmulationStation/emulationstation
```

I tried this as well:

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup & pkill lxsession & 
writevt /dev/tty1 'emulationstation'
```

My aim is to log out of the LXDE session and run EmulationStation on my Raspberry Pi with a bash script. I'm using `pkill lxsession;` to bypass lxsession's logout confirmation dialog.

As it stands, this script just gets me to the command line from a working LXDE desktop. Thanks for reading.

Comment: +1 well formulated. I don't think an ideal callback-event solution is possible. You could conditionally check the lxsession-status in a looping bash script which runs in the background and has a certain timeout period for each cycle....

Comment: How are you starting LXDE on your system?  startx, startlxde, gdm?  for some of these, you could add some lines to .xinitrc to run a process after LXDE ends

Comment: I've been using startx. EmulationStation starts on boot.

Answer (score 0):

Dont EmulationStation need some sort of X server running in the background for it to work?

IF not, then try the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
pkill lxsession;

sleep 5
su -c sh /home/pi/RetroPie/EmulationStation/emulationstation

exit
```

It could also be that when you log out of your lxde session the emulationstation dosent have a usershell to open it, therefore "su -c"
I'm not sure if its going to work but I hope you solve it. :)